# How does one create a bar heat map in SSRS?

Tags: sql-server, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2008-r2

How does one create a bar heat map in SSRS?  The only options I see is a map of USA.  I'm interested in creating a bar heat map. I'm using SSRS 2008.

Comment: As far as I can recall there's no native bar heatmap chart. So you need to use a pre calculated stacked bar chart with an each segment being the correct value to reflect the colour you want. If this is of interest I can try harder to recall how I did it. You'll need something along these lines: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd239350.aspx to enforce certain colours for certain series values

Comment: Thank you Nick McDermaid.  Yes I'm interested in how you did this.  I would greatly appreciate it if you provided me guidance on how to do this.

Comment: I don't have the report to hand, but do you know how many data points you have? Basically what I would do first is cook up a dataset in a stored procedure that contains as many rows as datapoints. The first column represents the category (which vertical line you are representing). The next column represents the series in the chart. It's a value corresponding to the heat value, i.e. 1-10. Then next column is simply a value of 1. If you use this dataset in a stacked column chart, you get X columns of stacked bars. Each bar has a series of Y series values all with a value of 1

Comment: So a chart with 5 columns and a height of 12 has 60 records in a three column table. The first column represents each vertical bar. The second column represents a single segment in that vertical bar. The third column is a '1' which is just saying that series is 1 long. Beware.... I suspect if you have more than a couple of thousand data points this isn't gong to work well. You might need to embed some kind of web rendering tool instead.

Answer (score 0):

The links shown below are parts 1 & 2 of a four part explanation and do an excellent job of describing how the process works.

1/4
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/davidlean/2009/02/16/sql-reporting-how-to-conditional-color-14-the-basics-report-expressions-custom-code/

2/4
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/davidlean/2009/02/16/sql-reporting-how-to-conditional-color-24-functions-for-tables-charts/